# Spray-Json serialize interface type

Tags: scala, serialization, spray-json

using spray-json how can I serialize following class

```
case class Vegetable(name: String, color: String, seller:ISeller)
```

here ISeller is a Java Interface. I am new to spray-json an not sure how this can be serialized and deserialized.

I tried this but it gives runtime error

```
implicit val VegetableFormat = jsonFormat3(Vegetable)
```

Any pointer here will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a way to convert to/from JSON for your ISeller object.
In addition to code you supplied you need to define formatter for ISeller like the following:

```
  implicit object ISellerJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[ISeller] {
    def write(c: ISeller) = JsNull

    def read(value: JsValue) = null
  }
```

The snippet above just ignores ISeller so vegetable.toJson would produce:

```
{"name":"Onion","color":"red","seller":null}
```

If you want to read/write something more meaningful you can implement more complex logic. See the "Providing JsonFormats for other Types" section in https://github.com/spray/spray-json .

Comment: Thanks, but where should I define the ISellerJsonFormat?

Comment: You can define it in the same source file before definition of vegetableFormat.